# Windows tar command: exclude folder in current folder but not subfolders

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, tar

I am trying to archive some folders with the tar command in Windows, and I would like to exclude a directory in the current folder, but not in subfolders.

The example below is using the technique described in this answer, but it appears not to work on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders

`tar -c -f ../test.tar .`

`tar -t -f ../test.tar`

```
./
./one/
./two/
./two/two.txt
./one/two/
./one/two/two.txt
```

`tar --exclude "./two" -c -f ../test.tar .`

`tar -t -f ../test.tar`

```
./
./one/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows `tar` command is bsdtar from [libarchive](https://www.libarchive.org/), not the GNU tar found on Linux.

The pattern syntax used by libarchive is not documented (docs claim it is like tcsh's glob syntax but that doesn't seem to be exactly the case), but [apparently](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/blob/60f086b37fc40952530d385e9f7a05ebec3dd9ad/libarchive/archive_pathmatch.c#L389C5-L389C12) it requires the `^` prefix to "anchor" the pattern to the beginning of the path:

```
bsdtar --exclude="^two"
```

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076083/how-to-make-tar-exclude-behave-consistently-across-nix-environments)